# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type android.net.Uri getting value to object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `user node` on Firebase Database that saves an url to profile picture of each user. The problem is that on Firebase it's a string and on my code, the property is an `Uri`.

I know it's easy to convert a string from Firebase to an Uri using `Uri.parse()`
But my question here is if its possible to **map this `string` to an object that has `Uri` property**:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = data.getValue(User.class); // Can't convert String to Uri
            contactList.add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can't just parse it in this case. **Any workaround?** I don't want to change my `User` object before being sure that there's any other better sollution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement to pass a class instance to Realtime Database using `getValue(class)` to get the data out of a snapshot.  If you require some custom mapping to get data into an object, you can simply access the data in the snapshot as using [data.getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue()) with no parameters.  If the child you queried has other children, it will return a `Map<String, Object>`.  The keys of the map will be the names of the children, and the values will be the data.  You can then convert any strings to an Uri if you want.

Comment: Can you give me some directions on how to convert the Object received from Firebase to a Map<String, String> ?

Comment: Just access each field value individually and cast it or convert it to a string with toString().

Comment: Thank's for helping me to fill some gaps I was missing. By the way, what a honor to being answered by you that helps me a lot with your videos Doug! By the way, [here is the the project I used the solution] (https://github.com/LeonardoRick/whatsapp-clone/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/whatsapp_clone/fragment/ContactFragment.java) if someone reaches this problem: